# Did i just destroy my work by incorrectly using git rebase

Tags: git, version-control, rebase, git-rebase

I executed the following line:

```
git rebase -i dev --onto master
```

I figured this would cut my dev branch and paste it on top of my master branch. And the -i would let me collapse the changesets.

But when it brought up the editor, I did not see any of the changesets. All I saw was "noop". So I just exited it. And then I look at my git history, all my changes are gone. My dev branch is at the same place my master is at!

Can some one help me recover? Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Git makes it hard to lose work.

Run:

```
git reflog
```

Than look for the commit that was just before the rebase

Then check it out

```
git checkout <sha>
```

Look around, is it the version you wanted to recover?

If so, create a branch here

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you!

Comment: _Git makes it hard to lose work_ It sure makes it easy to screw it up though